# r2dbc : Log-print connection pool details after every DB operation-r2dbc postgres

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

I am using r2dbc pool and implemented r2dbcEntityTemplate for DB operation.

I want to analyze connection pool details print log after executing every query(how many connections used,time etc.) how can I achieve this.

I tried logging but didn't worked.

```yaml
io.r2dbc.postgresql: TRACE
io.r2dbc.postgresql.client: TRACE
io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactory: TRACE
```

```java
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration configuration =
        PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
            .host(host)
            .port(port)
            .database(database)
            .schema(schema)
            .username(username)
            .password(password)
            .build();

    ConnectionFactory fg = new PostgresqlConnectionFactory(configuration);
    ConnectionPoolConfiguration connectionPoolConfiguration =
    ConnectionPoolConfiguration.builder(fg)
        .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofMillis(maxIdleTime)).acquireRetry(acquireRetry)
        .initialSize(initialSize).maxSize(maxSize).build();
    return new ConnectionPool(connectionPoolConfiguration);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your `application.yml` file:

`logging.level.io.r2dbc.pool: DEBUG`

You will receive information like: Obtaining connection / Releasing connection.

At the moment they don't expose any statistics regarding the entire pool connections like Hikari.